# certificate errors via chrome and IE

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, internet-explorer, certificate

When trying to access gmail.com via chrome I get this error message:

> Net::ERR_CERT_INVALID

The same error message appears with ninite.com or twitter.com - drive.google.com, youtube.com or facebook.com (all with https) on the other hand are just fine. The access to these sites is the same using IE.

My OS is windows XP with service pack 3. The system time is correct. The certificate is valid until April 13, 2015. Chrome is up to date # 40 (tried the beta version # 41 as well). Browsing incognito still gets the error message. I have deleted all of the browsers data and restored the browsers to the default settings which didn't solved the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the time and date on your PC.

Comment: The time and date are correct.

Comment: Are you going through a proxy?

Comment: There is no proxy.

Comment: Instead of adding new details in comments, you need to edit them into your question

Answer (score 1):

it was SSL certificate problem, thisis my way to fix this problem:

Assuming your time, date & time-zone settings are all correct...
Open Internet Explorer (only!) to http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com | Select CUSTOM and scan | Install any security updates offered.

• If a Root Certificates update and/or KB971029 is listed in the Optional Software updates category on the left-hand side of the scan results window, install it/them to take full advantage of WinXP's enhanced security.

• Tip: Do NOT install any other Optional Software updates nor any Optional Hardware updates!

Control Panel>Programs>turn windows features on or off>check all for internet.

if the methods not solve you must Purchase a full CERT

[www.cybersecuritycentral.com](http://www.cybersecuritycentral.com)